# mongo db insert big collections

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I have a mongo (version 2) in production in replicaset configuration (the next step is to add sharding).

I need to implement the following:

- Once a day i'll receive a file with millions rows and i shall load it into mongo.
- I have a runtime application that always read from this collection - very large amount of reads, and their performance is very important.
  The collection is indexed and all read perform readByIndex operation.

My current implementation of loading is:

1. drop collection
2. create collection
3. insert into collection new documents

One of the thing I see is that because of mongoDB lock my total performance getting worst during the loading.
I've checked the collection with up to 10Million entries.
For more that that size I think I should start use sharding

What is the best way to love such issue?
Or maybe should I use another solution strategy?

Comment: Is it important for your use case that all reads against this collection be "consistent" (in that they will see either the previous day's records for any of the 5M records, or the current day's records)? Or is it acceptable for some reads to come from yesterday's dump, and some from today's dump?

Comment: No, It's even Ok if during the load time some data will be 'not accessible' (because i'm dropping all values at the begining of the operation). But this of course if the load will take some reasonable time, say up to 1-2 hours. Otherwise I should probably have two collection and a metadata from which to read (each time like swap between them)

Comment: Between the data files for day N and day N+1, are records ever deleted? Or are they only ever added (or updated)? That is, does a record ever show up in day N which does not appear in day N+1?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two collections :)

- collectionA contains this day's data
- new data arrives
- create a new collection (collectionB) and insert the data
- now use collectionB as your data

Then, next day, repeat the above just swapping A and B :)

This will let collectionA still service requests while collectionB is being updated.

PS Just noticed that I'm about a year late answering this question :)